# Bond distance change on ionization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

The bond distance increases on ionization for the molecules C<sub>2</sub> and N<sub>2</sub>, but decreases for O<sub>2</sub> and F<sub>2</sub>. As far as I know, the bond should get longer when the amount of electrons involved decreases (which happens in ionization), so I have a hard time explaining this difference.

Comment: could you link some sources please